# Yodlee - Private Zone account creation wizard connection information

Tags: oauth, yodlee

I am trying to connect our developed code base to the Yodlee system from our white listed Private Zone IP.  As far as I can tell, the SOAP API and REST API are working but I received no direct instruction on the whereabouts of the Link Account Wizard.

The public testing server that I have been using to develop our interface is located here...

```
https://64.14.28.78/apps/addAccounts.pfmlaw.action
```

...according to the information I had received for the trial development and evaluation.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score -1):

We have already exchanged the details with you over an email.